# Continuous function on [0,1] with two maxima and one minimum

Tags: functions

I would like to construct a continuous function f:[0,1]->[0,1] that has two maxima at both .25 and .75, and one minimum at 0.5. Ideally something like what is on the graph below. Ideas are most welcomed.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \sin^2 (2 \pi x)$ satisfies all your requirements.

Given the shape of the graph, you are looking for a periodic function. $\sin^2 x$ only ranges from $0$ to $1$, and is also periodic.

However, the first maximum of $\sin^2 x$ when $x > 0$ is reached when $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Since the graph of $\sin(ax)$ is *compressed* by a factor of $a$, we can multiply by $2 \pi$ to compress the graph in the $x$-direction by $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$, which will make the first maximum have an $x$-coordinate of $\frac{\pi}{2} \times \frac{1}{2 \pi} = \frac{1}{4}$.

You can verify that $f(x)$ does have a minimum at $x=0.5$, and another maximum at $x=0.75$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose minimum := local minimum (since we cannot have distinct maximum). Also, minimum at $x$ means $f(y)=x$ is local minimum.

We know by continuity, that the minimum is between the two maximum, and the two maximum must be at the boundary $0,1$. (if not, between maximum and boundary, there is a new minimum.)

Hence you can construct $f$. (by connection by quadratic functions that are concave and convex).

Added: If minimum at $x$ means $f(x)$ is local minimum,

one example is $$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
|x|\;x\in[0,0.25]\\
|0.5-x|\;x\in(0.25,0.5]\\
|x-0.5|\;x\in(0.5,0.75]\\
|1-x|\;x\in(0.75,1]\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Sorry, I am still somewhat confused. I'd like to make something like the sine graph but on [0,1], with the local maximum at .25 and .75. Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Like $f(x)$ is $x^2+1/4$ on $[0,1/2]$, and $-(x-1)^2+0.75$ on other interval.

Comment: Does something like $\sin^2 (2 \pi x)$ work for you? The graph is [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5i994uy2ds).